# How to reply to a client who has fixed the problem themselves?

Tags: professionalism, email, customer-relation

I am trying to reply to a client who figured out and fixed the problem by themselves. I would like to appreciate the client in the e-mail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve handled this case many times. A simple reply is best:

> Great to hear you were able to solve the problem on your own and are up and running again! If you need anything, don’t hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 7):

If this was a support case, it sounds that the client missed something, but eventually manage to figure it out. That could well still be an issue, as it sounds like something in your documentation may not have been as clear as it could be.

In that case I'd suggest something like:

> Good job, and thanks very much for letting us know! I've flagged this up with our documentation team in any case to see if this is an area we can clarify in the future.

That shows you've appreciated their time letting you know it's an issue they've solved (rather than just ghosting you) and also that you're still trying to learn and improve your product from it.

In case it's not clear, you should of course *actually* follow through with this and then forward to the relevant team.